Separation properties of weak topology on $\ell^2$
If $\ell^2$ is given weak topology, call the resulting space $X$, then it's easy to show that it's $T_4$:
Since $X$ is a Hausdorff topological vector space, it must be Tychonoff.
Moreover, $X$ is $\sigma$-compact since the closed ball is compact by Banach-Alaoglu theorem, hence Lindelof. And since regular Lindelof spaces are normal, $X$ must be $T_4$.
Does $X$ satisfy $T_5$ or $T_6$ axiom of separation?
The properties of topological vector spaces like compactness of their subspaces are wildly studied, but nowhere could I find about things like when they satisfy even the $T_4$ axiom, let alone $T_5$ or $T_6$.

Yes, $\ell^2$ with its weak topology is $T_6$.
To see this, let $U\subseteq \ell^2$ be an open set. Then $U$ can be written as a countable union of open balls, since they form a basis of $\ell^2$, and $\ell^2$ is Lindelof.
Since every open ball is a countable union of closed balls, $U$ is a countable union of closed balls.
By Banach-Alaoglu theorem, a closed ball in $X$ is compact. So if $U\subseteq X$ is open, it's open in $\ell^2$, so a countable union of closed balls, so its a countable union of compact sets of $X$. This shows that $U$ is an $F_\sigma$-set, hence $X$ must be $T_6$, and in fact, that every open subspace of $X$ must be $\sigma$-compact.
Note that $X$ is not a Baire space so this is not in contradiction with the theorem that every Hausdorff $\sigma$-compact topological group which is a Baire space must be locally compact.
The same argument applies to any reflexive separable Banach space, so that they are $T_6$ in their weak topology, for example $L^p$ where $1 < p < \infty$.

Alternative proof:
$X$ as a continuous image of separable metrizable space $\ell^2$ is a cosmic space (actually, it's an $\aleph_0$-space), so that it's hereditarily Lindelof and regular, which implies that it's perfectly normal, see this post

Great proofs, Jakobian.
